# Is there a easy way to remove items from an array?

Tags: c

I have two lists.

```
char *name[] =  {"RGS", "O", "NRGY", "SIG", "BML-O", "BHI", "KSU", "ORN"};
char *name_to_remove[] =  {"RGS", "O", "NRGY"};
```

Is there a effective way to take a list of items and remove it from another list?  I have implemented my own version but I think its pretty inefficient.  Its basically makes a copy of the name list and then using a a nested for loop that goes through both the duplicated name & name_to_remove lists and marks any item that repeats to "remove". Finally I go through the list and copy all items except the ones with values 'remove'.  Its horribly ugly and I suspect inefficient. A problem I'm having trouble with(haven't dealt with it before) is I'm not sure if its possible to remove an item from an array if the array is a fixed size in memory, so I originally tried to change the values and then add the values into a new array(same size as original - the size of the array of items I want to remove).

I can't see a better way to do it, memcmp seemed promising because it can compare two lists but I haven't been able to figure how it fits. I know C is not python but here's how I do it cleanly in python:

```
for item in name_to_remove:
    name_copy.remove(item)
```

maybe under the scenes, the python command is doing as many loops as I'm doing but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is to use appropriate data structure. Python list is definitely not implemented as plain C array of strings (just because you can store objects of different types in Python list). So the data structure you are looking for is probably either a [*linked list*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) or a [*hash table*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable).

Comment: how would a linked list be useful here?

Comment: @chris Because if `name` was a linked list you could just free() the nodes that need to be deleted (and repoint the "next" pointer of the previous node to the following node). However, whether the overhead of a linked list is worth it depends entirely on how often you need to modify (midway) the list/array. Depending on the case a dynamic array or a plain static array may be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

> Its basically makes a copy of the name list and then using a a nested for loop that goes through both the duplicated name & name_to_remove lists and marks any item that repeats to "remove". Finally I go through the list and copy all items except the ones with values 'remove'.

Instead of marking anything, you could just copy any item you find in `name` that is *not* in `name_to_remove`and store it in a new array, and then trash the old `name` array.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of strings does not matter, you can sort both arrays to find duplicates, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARR_SIZE(array) sizeof(array)/sizeof(const char *)

int compare (const void * a, const void * b) {
    return strcmp(*((const char**)a), *((const char**)b));
}

int main(void) {
    const char *name[] =  {"RGS", "O", "NRGY", "SIG", "BML-O", "BHI", "KSU", "ORN"};
    const char *name_to_remove[] =  {"RGS", "O", "NRGY"};
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    qsort(name, ARR_SIZE(name), sizeof(const char*), compare);
    qsort(name_to_remove, ARR_SIZE(name_to_remove), sizeof(const char*), compare);
    while (i != ARR_SIZE(name) && j != ARR_SIZE(name_to_remove)) {
            int diff = strcmp(name[i], name_to_remove[j]);
            if (diff == 0) {
                    name[i] = NULL;
                    i++;
                    j++;
            } else if (diff < 0) {
                    i++;
            } else {
                    j++;
            }
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i != ARR_SIZE(name) ; i++)
            if (name[i])
                    printf("%s\n", name[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution is nice if you actually want to keep the array sorted, but if you only care about deleting matching elements, I hope it's clear to everyone that this is quite inefficient.

Comment: @WillBuddha This solution is `O(N*logN)` - more efficient than OP's `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

you could make a hash map, then loop through one array and test via `mapOfRemovableWords.contains(words[i])` and using that to decide if you should copy the element to a new array(or the front of itself).

You could also sort both arrays, and then iterate through them at the same time. Use the fact that if you're at a position where a word is greater than the current word in the other list, then it's not in the other list. You iterate one, and then decide if you need to iterate the other, and repeat until you've fully moved through both.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the python version isn't much more efficient than your code.

That said, you can certainly improve your implementation. Remember, the C array is really just a block of memory with a bunch of pointers to the beginnings of the strings. Since you're not creating new strings, you can always reuse the string pointers.

Conceptually, loop over your array, setting the pointer to null if the value is in the list to remove. Then use malloc() to create a new array of the appropriate size. Loop over the old array, copying the non-null pointers to the new array.

This way you've got 2 loop iterations and a single malloc.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate the first array at compile time, then its size is fixed and I believe it wouldn't be possible to subsequently reclaim any of the memory by "deleting" selected elements. I would suggest either implementing a linked-list that you can dynamically allocate, and subsequently `free()` parts of whenever you wish to remove an item, or, better yet, a more efficient data structure such as a binary search tree.